# NSThread detachNewThreadSelector in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, multithreading

The app works correctly in iOS 7 but when I mad the switch over to iOS 8, the app doesn't work the way it's suppose to.  While in debug mode, the NSThread detachNewThreadSelector function in the app is called to create a busy box in the foreground to prevent user access. The main thread continues on and calls a web service to retrieve data.  Once data is received, another detachNewThreadSelector is called to dismiss the first thread.

In iOS 8, when I step through in debug mode, after reaching the detachNewThreadSelector, nothing happens. The code in the first thread isn't executed.  The main thread continues to on and calls a web service to retrieve data.  Once the data is received, the second detachNewThreadSelector is reach but the code isn't executed as well until it reaches the end of the viewdidload function.

The code for dismissActivityIndicator is executed in the CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION which will generate an 'Attempt to dismiss from view controller' error.  It then steps into the __CFRunLoopDoSources0, and then executes the code for showActivityIndicator in the __CFRunLoopRun.  This causes the app to create a busy box with no way to dismiss it since the dismissActivityIndicator had already been executed.  Not really sure why the functions are called in reverse and at the end of the viewdidload function.

This project was pass on to me so I'm unfamiliar on how generate a pop up view to block the main thread until data is fetch from a source.  I need a quick fix or explanation to what is happening to repair the iOS 8 problem.

```
-(void)callService{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(showActivityIndicator) toTarget:self withObject:NULL];
sleep(1); 

    //call web service

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(dismissActivityIndicator) toTarget:self withObject:NULL];
}


-(void)showActivityIndicator{
    UISplitViewController *splitVC = [[self navigationController] splitViewController];
    UINavigationController *detailVC = [[splitVC viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];

    activityIndicatorVC = [[ActivityIndicatorVC alloc] init];
    [activityIndicatorVC setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
    [activityIndicatorVC setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];

    [detailVC presentViewController:activityIndicatorVC animated:NO completion: nil];
    CGRect r2 = CGRectMake(detailVC.view.bounds.size.width/2 - 80,
                       detailVC.view.bounds.size.height/2 - 150, 160, 160);
    r2 = [detailVC.view convertRect:r2 toView:activityIndicatorVC.view.superview.superview];
    activityIndicatorVC.view.superview.frame = r2;
}

-(void)dismissActivityIndicator{
    UISplitViewController *splitVC = [[self navigationController] splitViewController];
    UINavigationController *detailVC = [[splitVC viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
    [detailVC dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> The main thread continues on and calls a web service to retrieve data
>
> I'm unfamiliar on how generate a pop up view to block the main thread until data is fetch from a source.

Don't do these sort of things on the main thread! problems like this solve themselves if you use the main thread only for UI, and certainly never for anything that has to wait on something else.

you are also doing `sleep(1);` on the (presumably) main thread which is bad for similar reasons. Furthermore, you almost should never need to use `sleep` with appropriate design. Use of `sleep` is a good indicator you don't understand threading.

**Now on to an answer (maybe)**

I'm having difficulty understanding why you are detaching `showActivityIndicator` and `dismissActivityIndicator` to their own threads. UI operations on anything but the main thread is *usually* not only undefined behavior (not thread safe), but a bad idea in general.

Secondly, you are detaching them to different threads so they both run *simultaneously*. Obviously this is *not* what you want. The `dismissActivityIndicator` needs to be ran after the webservice call returns, not before. You removed the actual calls between `showActivityIndicator` and `dismissActivityIndicator` from your code, so who knows what is actually going on here; I'm simply guessing.

It ought to be the webservice call that is executed on its own thread. Then you would utilize completion handlers (on the main thread) to dismiss whatever UI elements need dismissing.

Comment: This function is an update function that calls data that is essential for the app to function.  That is the reason why the main thread is block until the data is received.

Comment: @vily that is *not* a good reason to block the main thread. I can't think of *any* reason to ever block the main thread.

Comment: The main functionality is to run the showActivityIndicator and the main thread simultaneously until the large amount of data is retrieve and the dismissActivityIndicator will remove the first thread after the web service call is done to make the app usable, which works in iOS 7.  This function is an initialization/update function.  The app will not work until data is initialized or correct data will not be shown if no update is done in the beginning of the work day.  The reason to why it must be done at this time is because the app is meant to be used where no internet connection is available

Comment: @vily i promise I understand all that; you are still going about it entirely the wrong way. you will always have problems doing UI manipulation from background threads and blocking the main thread is *always* a bad idea. End of story. clearly you dont believe me, but im done trying to convince you. good luck trying to solve your problem with broken fundamental principles of threading.

Comment: I do agree with what you say but I don't have time to rewrite the app correctly.  I am using a hack for iOS 8. dispatch_queue_t background_queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, NULL);
dispatch_async(background_queue, ^{
    // do some stuff that takes a long time here...
    [self showActivityIndicator];
    // follow up with some stuff on the main queue
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Typically updating the UI on the main thread.
    });
});  works for iOS 8 but not iOS 7.  I'm using a condition

Comment: if statement to make it work.  Ideally I would like to use one set of code that is usable between both system version.  Any idea to what is happening?